# 2X RDP-Client on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

Does anybody know if 2XClient (RDP) is supported in Ubuntu 13.10, I installed it but it wont start (no error message, nothing happens)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running /opt/2X/Client/bin/2XClient from the console? That may show some error message.

I'm trying to get it working on 13.10 64-bit, but that is proving tricky as they don't officially support it.

Update: I've just found out that there is a 2X Chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/2x-client-for-rdpremote-d/jbefefbcoggageojgcmipnfgjlekmpjp?hl=en

This works on 32 and 64 bit.